# How to customise the Button on UIActionSheet?

Tags: iphone, uiactionsheet

I want to change `width & height`, etc. of the button of `UIActionSheet`

```
UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@**"Done"**,nil];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest against doing this.  The button sizes and shapes in a UIActionSheet are designed the way they are for accessibility reasons.  They are also consistent across all applications on the platform, so users are familiar with them.  From the [iPhone Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/ModalViews/ModalViews.html#//apple%5Fref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH11-SW8):

> Because users are accustomed to the
>   appearance and behavior of these
>   views, it’s important to use them
>   consistently and correctly in your
>   application.

If you change these sizes, not only might you make your application less usable, but that may violate Apple's [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/ModalViews/ModalViews.html#//apple%5Fref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH11-SW8), leading to a rejection of your application when submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own actionsheet analog.