# how to remove the separator line from the UIActionsheet in ios 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiactionsheet

[image]In IOS7 by Default UIActionsheet coming like below image can we remove the separator line?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to subclass and change see here: [How to customize Buttons in UIActionSheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568308/how-to-customize-buttons-in-uiactionsheet)

Or there are some amazing examples here that you can use of custom UIActionSheet type classes:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=uiactionsheet

Comment: i dont want to use any custom controller because in earlier version i'm using default UIActionSheet code.

Comment: Check my edit, maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568308/how-to-customize-buttons-in-uiactionsheet