# Changing UIActionSheet width

Tags: iphone, uiactionsheet

By default, `UIActionSheet` in Landscape mode for iPhone takes the width of screen (480).

I tried to minimize the width. How can we change the Width and Will Apple accepts this behaviour?

Full code:

```
actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil,nil]; actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque; actionSheet.delegate = self; [actionSheet showInView:self.view]; [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0 , 0, 200, 320)];
```

Comment: I tried to set bounds for UIAction sheet.                  [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0 , 0, 200, 320)];

Comment: actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];

actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
actionSheet.delegate = self;
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
[actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0 , 0, 200, 320)];

Comment: you must read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1860168/932011) You can using uiactionsheet using [UIView](https://github.com/homeyer/CustomUIActionSheet).  you can create a custom view that slides up like an action sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this ability is built into UIActionSheet as I am sure I haven't seen it implemented in any app. I would create a custom UIView and use a UIViewAnimation to slide it up from the bottom of the screen. If you wanted it to prevent access to the view behind your custom action sheet you would need to create a view to go between your main view and custom action sheet which covers the full size of the screen.